# Rspec: Capybara server map a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, rack

I have a set of files in a folder under *spec/support/fixtures* directory. I need those files to be accessible through an uri such as `"http://127.0.0.0:#{Capybara.current_session.server.port}/test_fixtures"`

After many trail and errors I ended up the following solution: In *rails_helper.rb* I added the following code:

```
Capybara.app = Rack::Builder.new do
  map '/' do
    run Rails.application
  end
  map '/test_fixtures' do
    run Rack::File.new('spec/support/fixtures')
  end
end.to_app
```

It works well, but the solution to re-create Capybara app does not seem elegant to me. I'm looking for a better solution... or is it ok like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your stated goal you have implemented things correctly and that is exactly what the `Capybara.app` setting is meant for. The only thing I would recommend doing is moving it into a separate file and requiring that file in your rails_helper.